# Using Python to change the date on an xml document

Tags: python, xml, datetime

I have an xml in this form

```
<project name="Hello World">
        <testfile name="testfile1">
                <type>TXT</type>
                <size>1000</size>
                <lastModified>2014-08-03 03:40:00</lastModified>
        </testfile>
        <testfile name="testfile2">
                <type>PDF</type>
                <size>500</size>
                <lastModified>2015-09-23 17:40:17</lastModified>
        </testfile>
</project>
```

This is an .xml file containing info about my project, so I can update my testfiles should they are more than 3 months old.

Right now, i'm stuck trying to figure out how to change the element in the .xml file. This is my code so far...

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import sys
from datetime import datetime
def updateLastModified(self):
        today = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') # This variable stores todays date and time stamp for future reference. We shouldn't compute a new one every time.
        today = datetime.strptime(today, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') 
        # Now we need to iterate through all the testfiles in our metadata and update their lastModified tag with the current date.
        for testfile in self.getMetadataRoot().findall('testfile'):
            lastmodified = testfile.find('lastModified')    # get the lastmodified field in it's whole, so we can modify it.
            previous_update = datetime.strptime(lastmodified.text, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') # get the previous date from the lastmodified field and translate it from the str format

            if previous_update < today:
                lastmodified.text = str(today.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
                self.getMetadataTree().write(self.meta_file)
```

But for some reason, the meta_file is not changing... What am I doing wrong???

The problem is after the `if` statement, where the file is not being modified

here are the other methods i'm using in this class:

```
def __init__(self, filepath):
        self.meta_file = filepath

def getMetadataTree(self):
    return ET.parse(self.meta_file)

def getMetadataRoot(self):        
    tree = self.getMetadataTree()
    root = tree.getroot()
    return root
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your definition of `self.getMetadataTree()` re-parse the input file every time it gets called. So in the line `self.getMetadataTree().write(self.meta_file)`, it parse the meta file and write it back (the same info). All previous modification to timestamp is not relevant (it's a different instance of `ElementTree`).

I guess you want to do something like this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import sys
from datetime import datetime

class TimestampUpdater(object):

    def __init__(self, filepath):
        self.meta_file = filepath
        self.tree = ET.parse(self.meta_file)

    def getMetadataTree(self):
        return self.tree

    def getMetadataRoot(self):        
        return self.tree.getroot()

    def updateLastModified(self):
            today = datetime.now()
            for testfile in self.getMetadataRoot().findall('testfile'):
                lastmodified = testfile.find('lastModified')
                previous_update = datetime.strptime(lastmodified.text, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
                if previous_update < today:
                    lastmodified.text = today.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
                    self.getMetadataTree().write(self.meta_file)

def print_file_content(filename):
    """Print contents of a file."""
    with open(filename, 'r') as fh:
        for line in fh:
            print line.rstrip()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    metafile = 'test.xml'
    print "\n====Before updating:===="
    print_file_content(metafile)
    updater = TimestampUpdater(metafile)
    updater.updateLastModified() 
    print "\n====After updating:===="
    print_file_content(metafile)
```

Output:

```
====Before updating:====
<project name="Hello World">
        <testfile name="testfile1">
                <type>TXT</type>
                <size>1000</size>
                <lastModified>2016-08-07 16:58:23</lastModified>
        </testfile>
        <testfile name="testfile2">
                <type>PDF</type>
                <size>500</size>
                <lastModified>2016-08-07 16:58:23</lastModified>
        </testfile>
</project>

====After updating:====
<project name="Hello World">
        <testfile name="testfile1">
                <type>TXT</type>
                <size>1000</size>
                <lastModified>2016-08-07 16:58:36</lastModified>
        </testfile>
        <testfile name="testfile2">
                <type>PDF</type>
                <size>500</size>
                <lastModified>2016-08-07 16:58:36</lastModified>
        </testfile>
</project>
```

Comment: thank you so much! I'm relatively new to python! It took me 2 days just to get to the stage that I was!